# Site always open in IE8 compatability view

Tags: internet-explorer, compatibility

Working on a site whenever i am opening it on IE8 its changes to following:

Browser Mode: IE8 Compatibility view
Document Mode: IE7 Standard

Is there any way my site always open on Standard Mode.

I am using HTML5 Doctype and also checked with following Meta but no success.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

Comment: You should check the browser config; that's about the only way that the site settings can be overriden to force compat mode. In particular, check the local intranet settings.

Comment: Local intranet settings means? please explore more.